# Stateful service reliable collection read operations

Tags: azure-service-fabric

For stateful services in a Service Fabric application, do read operations on reliable collections ever use the secondary replicas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens in the communication stack. When using remoting, you simply just have to specify the kind of replica you want. Example:

ServiceProxy.Create(serviceUri, patitionKey, TargetReplicaSelector.RandomInstance);

Keep in mind, this will take bandwidth away from replication traffic.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting/

Comment: If I ask for `TargetReplicaSelector.RandomReplica` or `RandomSecondaryReplica` and I try to write to a collection then will it throw an exception?

Comment: Yes it will. So you have to make sure to route writes to your primary.